# Can't Modify Wordpress Theme from Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, themes

Has anyone ever worked with the Booard theme created – but no longer sold or supported – by [Theme-Paradise](https://themeforest.net/user/theme-paradise)? My boss has asked me to update a simple button link on the page below and I can’t for the life of me figure out how to modify a page with this theme. As I'm new to the company I don't yet have access to the server to modify the theme files, so I'm confined to the WP dashboard. I've looked through the editor but no luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The page I need help with: http://www.tech-30.com/careers/

Comment: what you added exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, I found it. If you click on Edit Page > 'Screen Options' at the top of the page and enable 'Custom Fields' it opens up a JSON page builder with shortcode text field entries. I was able to change the link from there. It took a while to update so I wasn't seeing it on the site for whatever reason. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2):

I found it. If you click on Edit Page > 'Screen Options' at the top of the page and enable 'Custom Fields' it opens up a JSON page builder with shortcode text field entries further down on the page under the post field entry. I was able to change the link from there. It took a while to update so I wasn't seeing it on the site for whatever reason.